# Changing php and sql code so results dont add up and its either one or the other

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to change the rules of the following code at the bottom to the following rules:
Scoring

- Each correct score will score 5 points

  Each correct goal difference will score 3 points

  Each correct result will score 1 point

Example: if you choose a 2-0 result

- If the game finishes 2-0 you earn 5 points

  If the game finishes 3-1 or 4-2 you get 3 points

  If the game finishes 2-1 or 3-0 you will get 1 point

  If it finishes a draw or the opposing team wins you will receive 0 points

The problem is i want the player to either get the full score, or if not that then the goal difference bonus, and if not that the toto score, and if not that nothing, however at the moment the toto score and the goal difference bonus seem to be adding up and instead of getting 3 points for the goal difference bonus the player gets 4 points because they also end up getting the toto score, so it has to be one or the other.

The following code is where it all calculates, and i have tried if statements however they do not seem to work.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$prefix}scorehistory 
                 SET score = score * ( ( full * {$full} ) 
                +
                ( goal_diff_bonus * {$diff} )
                +
                ( toto * {$toto} )
                + 
                ( goal_bonus * {$goal} ) 
                ) 
    WHERE type = %d AND ranking_id = %d 
    AND user_id IN ( {$user_ids} )"
    , FOOTBALLPOOL_TYPE_MATCH, $calculate_this_ranking );
```

Comment: Sorry, my earlier answer might not have been right.  I stand behind, however, that you should always print out your query to test.  Before executing it, try something like `$sql="UPDATE {$prefix}scorehistory  SET score = score * ( ( full * {$full} )  + ( goal_diff_bonus * {$diff} ) + ( toto * {$toto} ) +  ( goal_bonus * {$goal} )   )  WHERE type = %d AND ranking_id = %d AN user_id IN ( {$user_ids} )"; echo($sql);`

Comment: its an entire script its quite alot of code and that just bugs the script,